# Matrix table whose columns are based on slicers selection, here more than one slicers will decide the columns of a table/matrix in power bi

Tags: matrix, powerbi, powerbi-desktop, slicers, dynamic-columns

I have to create a matrix whose columns are based on slicer selection.
Scenario
Table having a columns product type, attribute and values.
Slicer 1 has product type, slicer 2 has  again same column product type, and column 3 has again same column product type. On the basis of selection of all 3 slicers values now matrix will have columns as per respective slicer selected value.
With 1 slicer it is easily achievable however other 2 slicers are also here is the need.

Comment: Can you share a link to sample PBIX, or update you question with more detail on your data model, and what approach you took with the one slicer working.

Comment: It's resolved, using dax in field parameter